# Find the closest two points in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String TITLE = "Lab 11 by ";
    double [][] points = {{1,2,3},{0,0,2},{1,3,5},{0,1,1}};
    double minDistance = distanceBetween(points[0],points[1]);
    int pointNum1 = 0; int pointNum2 = 1;
    for(int p = 0; p < points.length-1; p++){
        for(int r = p +1; r< points.length;r++){
        if(distanceBetween(points[p],points[r])<minDistance){
        minDistance =distanceBetween(points[p],points[r]);
        pointNum1 = 1;
        pointNum2 = r;
        } 
}
}
    String output = " Find closest two points!" + "\n" + "Points to consider:  \n";
    output += showPoints(points);
    output += "\n" + "Minimum distance is " + minDistance + "." + "\n";
    output += " The closest two points are " + pointNum1 + " and " + pointNum2 + ".";


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output,TITLE,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } // end main
```

I think my problem is in here my two closest points are suppose to be 2 and 4 but mine prints out 1 and 3.

Comment: You know, the most helpful part of your code you have left out. Where is the `distanceBetween` method defined and can we see the code?

Comment: Without reviewing your code: 2&4 vs 1&3 sounds like you havn't realized, that arrays start at 0. You don't have a point 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning always value "1" to pointNum1, so this value will be always displayed:

```
pointNum1 = 1;
```

In pointNum2 you are assigning the array index. Arrays start in 0, not in 1, so you must assign:

```
pointNum2 = r + 1;
```

Even if your program gets the correct result, will output 1 and (correct point - 1).

Comment: It is the same problem as with pointNum2. Must assign: pointNum1 = p+1;, if you want to asign the position starting at 1 and not at 0.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You were always setting one of your values to 1 and ignoring the zero based index nature of arrays. Here's a corrected version of your test. I made some minor performance corrections and included my code for calculating the distance between the points.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String TITLE = "Lab 11 by ";
        double [][] points = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 0, 0, 2 }, { 1, 3, 5 }, { 0, 1, 1 } };
        double minDistance = 1000000000;
        int pointNum1 = -1;
        int pointNum2 = -1;
        for (int p = 0; p < points.length - 1; p++) {
            for (int r = p +1; r < points.length; r++) {
                double distance = distanceBetween(points[p], points[r]);
                if (distance < minDistance) {
                    minDistance = distance;
                    pointNum1 = p;
                    pointNum2 = r;
                } 
            }
        }

        // These lines simply move from the zero based indices to more meaningful numbers.
        pointNum1++;
        pointNum2++;

        System.out.println("The shortest distance is between point " +
            pointNum1 + " and point " + pointNum2 + ".");
    }

    private static double distanceBetween(double[] p1, double[] p2) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < p1.length; i++) {
            total += Math.pow(p1[i] - p2[i], 2);
        }

        return Math.sqrt(total);
    }
}
```